# How to create a custom JMeter Pre-Processor to convert a json payload into MQTT Binary packet

Tags: mqtt, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, java-websocket

I need a JMeter Pre Processor which will convert a JSON String into a MQTT packet i.e binary data. The binary data will then be sent over the web socket using the JMeter web socket plugin - https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers

I am relatively new to JMeter and would appreciate any help on this.  Please refer to my earlier question for the project scenario :

[Testing a MQTT Client using JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181976/testing-a-mqtt-client-using-jmeter/65182167#65182167)

Answer (score 1):

You kindly provided the [link](https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers#samplers) to the documentation which says:

> The request-response sampler, as well as the single-read and single-write samplers, support both text and binary frames. For binary frames, enter the payload in hexadecimal format, e.g. `0xca 0xfe` or `ba be`

So

1. Text data can be sent as they are (JSON is more or less plain text)
2. Binary (non-text) data needs to be converted to hex first

So you need to determine what exactly you need because your current requirement is a little bit vague and contraversial.

If you're looking for a function to convert string to hex - you can go for [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and something like:

```
def hex(byte[] data) {
    def rv = new StringBuilder();
    data.each { aByte ->
        rv.append('0x').append(String.format("%02x", aByte)).append(' ');
    }
    return rv.toString();
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)